# How to set order of columns where joins are included in select in Zend Framework

Tags: zend-framework, select, join

Do you know if in case as follows there is any way to set sequence of columns? which is first, which one is second etc?

```
$select->from(array('e' => 'equipment'), array(
                        'ID_equipment',
                        'nr_in',
                        'equipment_type_ID_equipment_type',
                        'serial_number',
                        'barcode',
                        'sys_create_date',
                        'sys_deleted',  
                        'status',       
                        'computer_unit_idcomputer_unit',    
                        'room_ID_room', 
                        'action_ID_action',     
                        'invoice_id_invoice',   
                        'quara',
                        'description'
    ));

$select->join(array('et' => 'equipment_type'), 'e.equipment_type_ID_equipment_type = et.ID_equipment_type', array('equipment_type_name'));
$select->join(array('i' => 'invoice'), 'i.id_invoice = e.invoice_id_invoice', array('invoice_number'));
```

These columns which come from joins are placed at the end of all columns and I would like to change placement of this.

Thank you in advance for any help.

Kind Regards,

Comment: Why do you need to change the order?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

initially it seems that placing:

'equipment_type_ID_equipment_type as equipment_type_name'

sets column in proper manner (after nr_in)